# About the definition of polyhedra in Rourke and Sanderson

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Rourke and Sanderson's Intro to PL topology and I'm having some trouble understanding their definition on polyhedra and since I can't find any other mention of this definition I thought about asking here.

In the book a set $P \subset \Bbb R^n$ is a polyhedron if each point $a \in P$ has a cone neighbourhood with compact base inside $P$, meaning that there is a compact subset $L\subset P$ so that

$$\{\lambda a+\mu b: b\in L,\ \lambda+\mu=1\text{ and } \lambda,\mu\ge0\}\subset P$$

What confuses me is that the empty set is not excluded in the choice of $L$ leading me to think that every singleton in $P$ could be a cone and so every set is a polyhedron. Well that's obviously wrong but I don't seem to understand why.

EDIT. I'm adding the definition of cone, since it's more likely the confusion to be there.

Let $aB$ be the set of all the line segments from $a$ to a point $b\in B$ so that $x = \lambda a + \mu b$ is uniquely expressed or equivalently $a\notin B$ and for different $b_1$, $b_2$ the arcs $[a,b_1]$, $[a,b_2]$ intersect only in $a$

Can you please help me?

Comment: If $L$ is empty, then I think your set is empty. It is tempting to think that $a$ would be in there, but for any $a,\mu,\lambda$ the set $\lbrace \lambda a+\mu b: b\in L\rbrace$ is empty if $L$ is empty.

Comment: For any function $f:X\to Y$, we have $\lbrace f(x):x\in\emptyset\rbrace=\emptyset$.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the case here. That book says that if $[A,B]=\{λa+μb: a \in A,b \in B\}$ and should $A$ be empty then $[A,B]=B$. It also says that the empty set is not excluded so that a point can be considered a polyhedron.

Comment: Plus, I don't think the problem is there. It seems logical that all the line segments connecting a point with the points of the empty set to be the original point itself

Comment: So the book defines $[A,\emptyset]=A$, which is fine, but it doesn't follow from the set-builder notation. I disagree with what you've written above. I would say "It is fair to legislate that...", however, to me at least, it seems logical that the set of line segments between a point and the empty set is itself empty.

Comment: No, the book says it's $A$, not empty.

Comment: So why didn't the book use $[\lbrace a\rbrace, L]$ if they had established the notation?

Comment: It does use it.

Comment: I do not agree with your edit. Consider $P = [0,2] \subset \mathbb{R}$ which is certainly a polyhedron. There are many cone neighborhods of $0$. In fact, for any compact $L \subset (0,2]$ we get $0 \in [0,L] \subset P$. But when $L$ is not a singleton, any two line segments from $0$ to $b \in L$ intersect in an interval.

Comment: These are not my definitions. In the case of $[0,2]$ the cone neighbourhoods of $0$ would have to have a singleton compact base only, according to Rourke and Sanderson's definitions. They also have examples showing this is not accepted as a cone neighbourhood in their definitions

Answer (score 1):

They have an *ad hoc* definition $a\emptyset=\{a\}$ alas. But that does not imply that every set is a polyhedron. What they need for $X$ to be a polyhedron
is for each $x\in X$ to have a neighbourhood in $X$ of the form $aL$. But
$a\emptyset =\{a\}$ is only open in $X$ iff $a$ is an isolated point of $X$.
So their convention does not allow all sets to be polyhedra.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused. The book says that $a\emptyset=\{a\}$ implies $\{a\}$ is a polyhedron. Their only demand for a cone neighbourhood is that $L$ be compact, which the $\emptyset$ is. So if $\{a\}$ is a polyhedron what is it's cone neighbourhood?